# nose.run() seems to hold test files open after the first run

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm having the same problem on Windows and Linux. I launch any of various python 2.6 shells and run nose.py() to run my test suite. It works fine. However, the second time I run it, and every time thereafter I get exactly the same output, no matter how I change code or test files. My guess is that it's holding onto file references somehow, but even deleting the *.pyc files, I can never get the output of nose.run() to change until I restart the shell, or open another one, whereupon the problem starts again on the second run. I've tried both `del nose` and `reload(nose)` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved* it with some outside help. I wouldn't consider this the proper solution, but by searching through sys.modules for all of my test_modules (which point to *.pyc files) and `del`ing them, nose finally recognizes changes again. I'll have to delete them before each nose.run() call. These must be in-memory versions of the pyc files, as simply deleting them out in the shell wasn't doing it. Good enough for now.

**Edit:**

*Apparently I didn't entirely solve it. It does seem to work for a bit, and then all of a sudden it won't anymore, and I have to restart my shell. Now I'm even more confused.